# In Joda-Time, set DateTime to start of month

Tags: java, date, jodatime

My API allows library client to pass Date:

```
method(java.util.Date date)
```

Working with [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), from this date I would like to extract the month and iterate over all days this month contains.

Now, the passed date is usually *new Date()* - meaning current instant. My problem actually is setting the new *DateMidnight(jdkDate)* instance to be at the start of the month.

Could someone please demonstrates this use case with [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)?

Comment: The question title should mention Joda Time.

Comment: It does "Could someone please demonstrates this use case with joda-time." I've added another note to make it more clear that this is a joda time question.

Comment: @MaximVeksler Lachlan Roche said *title* should mention Joda-Time. I made the edit.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Midnight at the start of the first day of the current month is given by:

```
// first midnight in this month
DateMidnight first = new DateMidnight().withDayOfMonth(1);

// last midnight in this month
DateMidnight last = first.plusMonths(1).minusDays(1);
```

If starting from a java.util.Date, a different DateMidnight constructor is used:

```
// first midnight in java.util.Date's month
DateMidnight first = new DateMidnight( date ).withDayOfMonth(1);
```

Joda Time java doc - https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/overview-summary.html

Comment: btw, on that "last" why not: 
DateMidnight last = first.plusMonths(1).minusDays(1); Same thing,just cleaner.

Comment: This answer was correct, but is now outmoded. Not every day in every time zone has a midnight. Joda-Time 2 added a method [`withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay()) to be used in place of the "midnight" features.

Comment: DateMidnight is now deprecated.  From JavaDoc: "The time of midnight does not exist in some time zones where the daylight saving time forward shift skips the midnight hour. Use LocalDate to represent a date without a time zone. Or use DateTime to represent a full date and time, perhaps using DateTime.withTimeAtStartOfDay() to get an instant at the start of a day."

Comment: `DateMidnight` is deprecated.

Answer (score 33):

An alternative way (without taking DateMidnight into account) to get the first day of the month would be to use:

```
  DateTime firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime().dayOfMonth().withMinimumValue();
```

Comment: Although the date would be the first of the month, the time would still be in the middle of the day.  Adding .withTimeAtStartOfDay() to the end would resolve this.

Comment: you can also add .dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue().hourOfDay().withMaximumValue() and can add the same with minutes of Hours... to be more precise

Answer (score 10):

## First Moment Of The Day

The [answer by ngeek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5805174/642706) is correct, but fails to put the time to the first moment of the day. To adjust the time, append a call to [`withTimeAtStartOfDay`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay--).

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.

org.joda.time.DateTime startOfThisMonth = new org.joda.time.DateTime().dayOfMonth().withMinimumValue().withTimeAtStartOfDay();
org.joda.time.DateTime startofNextMonth = startOfThisMonth.plusMonths( 1 ).dayOfMonth().withMinimumValue().withTimeAtStartOfDay();

System.out.println( "startOfThisMonth: " + startOfThisMonth );
System.out.println( "startofNextMonth: " + startofNextMonth );
```

When run in Seattle US…

```
startOfThisMonth: 2013-11-01T00:00:00.000-07:00
startofNextMonth: 2013-12-01T00:00:00.000-08:00
```

Note the difference in those two lines of console output: -7 vs -8 because of [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

---

Generally one should always specify the time zone rather than rely on default. Omitted here for simplicity. One should add a line like this, and pass the time zone object to the constructors used in example above.

```java
// Time Zone list: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html  (Possibly out-dated, read note on that page)
// UTC time zone (no offset) has a constant, so no need to construct: org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.UTC
org.joda.time.DateTimeZone kolkataTimeZone = org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" );
```

## java.time

The above is correct but outdated. The Joda-Time library is now supplanted by the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later.

The `LocalDate` represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone. A time zone is crucial in determine a date. For any given moment the date varies by zone around the globe.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneId );
```

Use one of the [`TemporalAdjusters`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) to get first of month.

```
LocalDate firstOfMonth = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth() );
```

The `LocalDate` can generate a `ZonedDateTime` that represents the first moment of the day.

```
ZonedDateTime firstMomentOfCurrentMonth = firstOfMonth.atStartOfDay( zoneId );
```

Answer (score 5):

Oh, I did not see that this was about jodatime. Anyway:

```java
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(date);
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

int min = c.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int max = c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
for (int i = min; i &lt;= max; i++) {
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, i);
    System.out.println(c.getTime());
}
```

Or using commons-lang:

```java
Date min = DateUtils.truncate(date, Calendar.MONTH);
Date max = DateUtils.addMonths(min, 1);
for (Date cur = min; cur.before(max); cur = DateUtils.addDays(cur, 1)) {
    System.out.println(cur);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the java basic api note. I've learned from this as well.

Answer (score 1):

`DateMidnight` is now deprecated.  Instead you can do:

```
LocalDate firstOfMonth = new LocalDate(date).withDayOfMonth(1);
LocalDate lastOfMonth = firstOfMonth.plusMonths(1).minusDays(1);
```

If you know the time zone use `new LocalDate(date, timeZone)` instead for greater accuracy.

You can also do `.dayOfMonth().withMinimumValue()` instead of `.withDayOfMonth(1)`

EDIT:

This will give you `12/1/YYYY 00:00` and `12/31/YYYY 00:00`.  If you rather the last of the month be actually the first of the next month (because you are doing a between clause), then remove the `minusDays(1)` from the lastOfMonth calculation

Comment: @Xylian I guess it depends on the interpretation of the question.  For the any day, it will give you midnight on the first of the month and midnight of the last day of the month.  If you want midnight of the first day of the next month, just remove the ".minusDays(1) from the second.  If you still think my answer is incorrect, please elaborate, because my unit tests say it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Start date and end date of month using this:

```
DateTime monthStartDate = new DateTime().dayOfMonth().withMinimumValue();
DateTime monthEndDate = new DateTime().dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue();
```